# Web app login issue with windows authenticaion on IIS

Tags: c#, authentication, iis, window

I am having a web application and to login into the system I am using the Windows Authentication, when I am using it through the "LocalHost" its working fine and whenever wrong user name and password put into the login form it is showing javascript popup, which is as per the expectation.
Now when I am moving my application to IIS, its throwing error whenever user puts the wrong user name and password instead showing the JavaScript Popup.

I am using the Forms Authentication in it. and using the Integrated Security=True in the connection string.

Comment: Your question is confusing, are you using windows authentication or forms authentication? Or is it some kind of a combination? When you say javascript popup, are you talking about the browser "Authentication Required" popup? Try to provide technical details, such as how you configured your setup, possible post anything related in your web.config.

Comment: Hi tewr I am using combination of both, its an intranet based application so first I am checking using windows authentication that it belongs to network or not, after that I am using the sql tables to check whether its the user of the application or not. Second thing I would like to add that I don't have access to the IIS server, so any changes in the IIS can be done through the Web.config file.

Comment: Post the security part of your web.config. Also - Are you using impersonation? If not, does your IIS appool account have the right to access  your sql server? Post the error coming from "throwing error". If there is nothing special there, consider turning off custom error messages to get a detailed message.

Comment: yes my iis pool has the access to the sql server, my problem is that when I am running this applicaton on my local environment its working fine when I am putting the wrong username password, but when I am putting it into IIS and putting wrong username and password its throwing error (Yellow screen of error)

Answer (score 0):

Set Forms Authentication = true

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771077(v=ws.10).aspx

The reason it was working before is because you were local using integrated windows login security.